# Похожие на Selenium инструменты для JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium

новичок в js, есть бот на Selenium Python, но че-то как-то не очень у меня получается его переписать на Selenium js, есть ли какой-то другой инструмент наподобие Selenium?

Comment: https://selenium-python.com/  почитай внимательно

Comment: `Че-то не получается`  - это не понятно, что именно не получается...

Comment: @Air, например вот такой код в Python `promo_code = WebDriverWait(DRIVER, 20).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, FIELD_PROMO_CODE))).text` будет ожидать 20 сек, если появится элемент, то сохранит текст элемента в переменную, и пойдет дальше, а в JavaScript `const promo_code = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(FIELD_PROMO_CODE)), 20 * 10 ** 3).then(element => console.log(element.type));` возвращает мне промис, хотя я бы хотел чтобы он дал мне текст и только после этого пошел дальше.
`findElement` из статьи тоже не работает.